# Importing limited data columns through SQL Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, loader

I need to import comma seperated (CSV) data file into oracle table. File has 160 columns and table has 65 columns only. I am wondering how to skip unwanted columns from the file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The [control file reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch05.htm#1656) can help you: use the `FILLER` syntax.